# Having docstrip place files in different folders

Tags: installing, documentation

I've written my own biblatex citation style and decided to put both the `bbx` and the `cbx` file in a `dtx` file to process that with docstrip. Now I would like to have docstrip place the files in my local folder `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/` and ...`/cbx/` respectively. My attempt at using the following `ins` file failed:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\usedir{~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/}
\generate{\file{blah.bbx}{\from{blah.dtx}{bbx}}}
\usedir{~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/}
\generate{\file{blah.cbx}{\from{blah.dtx}{cbx}}}
\end
```

It just places both files in the same directory as the `dtx` file. My guess is that I didn't quite understand the usage of `\usedir` in the docstrip manual ... Any help would be appreciated!

The `ins` and `dtx` file are both in `~/Library/texmf/tex/source/blah/` by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docstrip documentation:

```
\BaseDirectory
```

> This macro is administrator’s way of saying “yes, I want to use that
>   directories support of yours”. DocStrip will write only to current
>   directory unless your config has a call to this macro. (This means
>   DocStrip won’t write to random directories unless you tell it to,
>   which is nice.) Using this macro you can specify a base directory for
>   TEX-related stuff. E.g., for many Unix systems that would be

```
\BaseDirectory{/usr/local/lib/texmf}
```

> and for standard emTEX installation

```
\BaseDirectory{c:/emtex}
```

You need a more explicit approach:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\catcode`~=11
\BaseDirectory{~}
\DeclareDir{firstLabel}{Library/texmfa/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/}
\usedir{firstLabel}
\generate{\file{blah.bbx}{\from{blah.dtx}{bbx}}}
\end
```

Caveats:

1. I couldn't really test this, missing blah.dtx :)
2. The `~` is also messing up your code; remember it means "unbreakable space", so you have to make it a letter (that's what the mysterious catcode is there for).
3. It may not work anyway with `~`, try changing that to `\BaseDirectory{/home/koji}` or whatever your home dir is.
4. Depending on your system, you may have change the variable `openout_any` in your `texmf.cnf`. **Edit:** Since you seem to be using osx, this involves adding

   ```
   openout_any = a
   ```

   in your file

   ```
   /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
   ```

Comment: Just an aside: make very sure you don't mistype your paths, you can end up overwriting important files in your system ...

Comment: Hm, this still results in a `! I can't write on file ...` error by LaTeX. Could it be that I need to "reload" `texmf.cnf` and if yes, how does that work? And do I need to change the catcode of `~` back after I've used it for the filename?

Comment: @Jonathan: It works here, make sure of a few things: a) change ~ for your homedir; on OS X, it's a path of the form /Users/<username>. b) Watch carefully my DeclareDir definition, there's an intentional typo there: "Library/texmfa/tex" should be "Library/texmf/tex"!!

Comment: @Jonathan: also, the directories _have_ to exist before hand.

Comment: Ok, it worked now. Seems that the expansion of `~` didn't work, which is a pity because this means it only works for my user now. Is there a way to set `BaseDirectory` to my _local_ textree?

Comment: @Jonathan Since your .ins file is inside your local textree, you can use relative paths, like `\BaseDirectory{../../../tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/}`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Still, it would be nice to be able to do something like `\BaseDirectory{$TEXMF_LOCAL}` ...

Comment: A simpler, dirty solution would be using a shell script.